# Draw figure using LatexDraw

Tags: floats

I have drawn a figure using Latexdraw. My code is as follows:

```
   \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
 \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\begin{document}
\scalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-2.0)(7.464375,2.0)
\definecolor{color11}{rgb}{0.9490196078431372,0.06666666666666667,0.06666666666666667}
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.9882352941176471,0.027450980392156862,0.027450980392156862}
\definecolor{color7}{rgb}{0.9725490196078431,0.043137254901960784,0.043137254901960784}
\psframe[linewidth=0.04,linecolor=color0,dimen=outer](1.8,2.0)(0.0,-2.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12,linecolor=color7](4.14,-0.92)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(6.9245315,1.37){\color{color11}HERE}
\end{pspicture} 
}

\end{document}
```

I want to make grids behind my figure. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add `showgrid=true` in optional argument:

```
  \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
 \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\begin{document}
\scalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,-2.0)(7.464375,2.0)
\definecolor{color11}{rgb}{0.9490196078431372,0.06666666666666667,0.06666666666666667}
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.9882352941176471,0.027450980392156862,0.027450980392156862}
\definecolor{color7}{rgb}{0.9725490196078431,0.043137254901960784,0.043137254901960784}
\psframe[linewidth=0.04,linecolor=color0,dimen=outer](1.8,2.0)(0.0,-2.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12,linecolor=color7](4.14,-0.92)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(6.9245315,1.37){\color{color11}HERE}
\end{pspicture} 
}

\end{document}
```